# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Sou novo em programação e estou tentando fazer um código simples de um exercício para calcular uma conta telefônica:

```
t = float(input('Digite a quantidade de minutos gasta: '))

if t < 200:
    p = t * 0,2
if t >= 200 and t < 400:
    p = t * 0,18
if t >= 400:
    p = t * 0,15

print('O preço da ligação foi de .2f reais.' %p)
```

Porém, ele está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
print('O preço da ligação foi de .2f reais.' %p)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

O que devo fazer? Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Está faltando um `%` na sua string `'O preço da ligação foi de .2f reais.'`, por isso o `.2f` acaba sendo interpretado literalmente (i.e. vai fazer parte da string final, sem modificações) e - como "sobrou" um argumento - ele te avisa do fato. Em outras palavras, sua string espera zero argumentos, e você passou um.

Para corrigir *este* erro, acrescente o `%` que ficou faltando:

```
'O preço da ligação foi de %.2f reais.'
```

E, como sugerido nas demais respostas, corrija também o uso inadequado da vírgula, pois espera-se o ponto como separador decimal (a vírgula serve para criar uma [tupla](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enupla), e é isso que está sendo armazenado na sua variável `p`). Também concordo com a sugestão de usar o padrão novo de formatação, que usa a função `format`, em vez do operador `%` (é mais organizado, possui mais funcionalidades, mais opções de formatação e de passagem de argumentos, etc).

Comment: Nossa, eram erros bem simples, e eu nem percebi, rs.
Quanto aos operadores, acho mais prático usar o '%' ao invés do 'format' quando eu não precisar repetir os argumentos na string. Mas isso é por agora, talvez no futuro eu me acostume com o 'format'.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro tem um erro anterior complicando o funcionamento. As linguagens de programação costumam usar a notação numérica americana portanto a separação das casas decimais é feita com um ponto e não uma vírgula como está no código. Corrija isto.

Python tem uma [nova forma de formatar dados](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/inputoutput.html), prefira esta forma:

```
"O preço da ligação foi de {0:8.2f} reais.".format(p)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/Format.py).

E agora tem algo mais novo ainda chamada [*f-string*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/323171/101).

Answer (score 3):

Como já mencionado o correto é representar esses [valores flutuantes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) com um ponto `.` e não uma vírgula `,`. Veja [**aqui**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) os problemas e limitações de valores flutuantes em Python.

Seu código deveria ficar parecido com isto:

```py
t = int(input("Digite a quantidade de minutos gasta: "))

if t < 200:
    p = t * 0.2
if t >= 200 and t < 400:
    p = t * 0.18
if t >= 400:
    p = t * 0.15

print ("O preco da ligacao foi de %.2f reais." % p) 
# Ou com a funcao format()
print ("O preco da ligacao foi de {0:.2f} reais".format(p))
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/GA4RvV)</kbd>

Dependendo do fator **localização**, o [separador decimal](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separador_decimal) pode ser diferente, ao invés de um ponto `.` pode ser uma vírgula `,`. Para obter essa informação pode-se usar a função [`nl_langinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/locale.html#locale.nl_langinfo) do módulo [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/locale.html#module-locale) com a opção [`RADIXCHAR`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/locale.html#locale.RADIXCHAR).

```py
import locale

print (locale.nl_langinfo(locale.RADIXCHAR))
```

Caso seja necessário calcular os valores tendo como [separador decimal](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separador_decimal) a `,` você pode usar a função [`atof`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/locale.html#locale.atof) para converter uma *string* em um valor flutuante. Veja uma demonstração:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import locale

# Em pt_BR vai o separador decimal é "."
print (locale.nl_langinfo(locale.RADIXCHAR)) 
# Mudamos o locale para Inglês - Dinamarca
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_DK.utf8')
# Em en_DK o separador decimal é ","
print (locale.nl_langinfo(locale.RADIXCHAR))

t = int(input("Digite a quantidade de minutos gasta: "))

if t < 200:
    p = t * locale.atof("0,2")
if t >= 200 and t < 400:
    p = t * locale.atof("0,18")
if t >= 400:
    p = t * locale.atof("0,15")

print ("O preco da ligação foi de %.2f reais." % p) 
# Ou com a função format()
print ("O preco da ligacao foi de {0:.2f} reais".format(p))
```