# Por que as f-strings não podem ser utilizadas como docstring?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Conforme a [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), tem-se:

> *A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition. Such a docstring becomes the `__doc__` special attribute of that object.*

Isto é, a *docstring* é uma string literal que é a primeira instrução de um módulo, classe ou função, que ficará acessível pelo campo `__doc__` do objeto.

```
def hello():
    'Exibe uma saudação'
    print('Hello')

print(hello.__doc__)  # Exibe uma saudação
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/LowestMedicalExpertise) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/acwoss/a4caa260dd991669f5472ee3a6b55d30)</sup>

Mas se tentarmos utilizar uma [*f-string*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), com formatação, o valor de `__doc__` será `None`.

```
__author__ = 'Anderson Carlos Woss'

def hello():
    f'Autor: {__author__}'
    print('Hello')

print(hello.__doc__)  # None
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SkyblueFantasticChapter) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/acwoss/d688d31ef6d67e01377f2b7157cbdc0f)</sup>

Por que as *f-string* não podem ser utilizadas como *docstring*?

Comment: Porque o Guido mandou! Agora que ele não manda mais, pode usar sim! :P :D Eu acredito ser uma limitação porque ele só consegue pegar um valor constante. Quando está usando interpolação aquilo é uma ação a ser executada no momento da execução para dar um resultado. Vale como resposta se elaborar um pouco mais?

Comment: Vale, principalmente se tiver fontes. O caminho é esse mesmo. A f-string deixa de ser literal por precisar tratar a interpolação e, por definição, não pode ser usada como docstring.

Comment: Acho que sim, achei fundamentação :)

Comment: Até porque a docstring é gerada em tempo de "compilação", não tempo de execução, então como garantiria o valor da variável? Nesse caso possui valor, mas imagina usar um parâmetro dentro da docstrings...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Porque a *f-string* deixa de ser literal e, por definição, deixa se ser uma candidata a ser *docstring*.

Também pelo fato que a *docstring* é gerada em tempo de compilação, quando gerado o byte-code que será interpretado - como o Maniero comento em sua [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/323183/5878), isso foi uma escolha de projeto; eles poderiam fazer o valor ser avaliado em tempo de execução, mas não viram motivos para tal. Assim, como garantir o valor dos objetos que serão interpolados? No caso da pergunta, a interpolação ocorre apenas com uma variável global e poderia gerar a *docstring* "Autor: Anderson Carlos Woss", mas e se eu fizer em algum outro ponto do código `__author__ = 'Foo'`, isso deveria alterar a *docstring*? Isso piora se considerarmos que poderíamos adicionar o valor de um parâmetro da função na *docstring*:

```
def hello(name):
    f'Saudação para {name}'
    print(f'Hello, {name}')
```

Neste caso, qual seria o valor de `hello.__doc__`? Uma opção seria considerar a *string* sem formatação como *docstring*, mas, novamente, isso foi uma escolha de projeto. Que sentido teria uma *docstring* com o valor `Autor: {__author__}`?

Quanto a não ser mais uma *string* literal, veja a diferença entre os *opcodes* gerados para uma *string* normal e uma *f-string*.

**String normal**

```
>>> print(dis.dis('"Hello"'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Hello')
              2 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

**F-String**

```
>>> print(dis.dis('f"Hello {name}"'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Hello ')
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (name)
              4 FORMAT_VALUE             0
              6 BUILD_STRING             2
              8 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Os passos extras, para formatar e construir a *string* final fazem com que a *f-string* deixe de ser apenas um valor literal e precise desta execução. Por exemplo, veja o *opcode* gerado quando é utilizado uma *string* literal como *docstring*:

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Hello world')
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (__doc__)

  3           4 LOAD_NAME                1 (print)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello')
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 POP_TOP
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Perceba que ele armazena a *string* dentro do objeto `__doc__`, seja ele do módulo, classe ou função. Porém, ao informar uma *f-string*, o resultado é:

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Hello ')
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (name)
              4 FORMAT_VALUE             0
              6 BUILD_STRING             2
              8 POP_TOP

  3          10 LOAD_NAME                1 (print)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello')
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 POP_TOP
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Ou seja, o interpretador irá avaliar a *f-string*, efetuar a interpolação dos valores e retornar a *string* final que, como não será mais uma *docstring*, será uma *string* avulsa no código e, portanto, descartada. Como não é informada uma *string* literal, a função acaba ficando sem uma *docstring*, por isso retorna `None`.

Answer (score 3):

O mecanismo da *docstring* deve ser muito simples, só ter uma valor constante que ficar armazenado em algum lugar e que se invocado ele é trazido à tona porque quem precisou dele. Não foi intuito da linguagem prover um mecanismo mais sofisticado. A *f-string* é mais sofisticada, ela tem execução de código para chegar em um resultado, porque a interpolação não ocorre magicamente só porque a sintaxe parece indicar isto, há a chamada de uma função que concatena adequadamente os textos necessários.

Isto pode ser confirmado quando abriram um [*bug* na documentação](https://bugs.python.org/issue28739) que foi acatado para indicar que não pode mesmo.

Poderiam ter optado por fazer uma mecanismo mais sofisticado que permitisse resolver em tempo de execução, nem seria muito fora da filosofia da linguagem, mas em geral não compensa, eu até questiono a necessidade deste tip ode coisa na forma atual, até porque a linguagem já possui forma mais sofisticada de fazer isto, apesar de exigir mais esforço. E até para fazer exatamente isto manualmente é bem simples.

Comment: "Poderiam ter optado por fazer uma mecanismo mais sofisticado que permitisse resolver em tempo de execução," - Não poderiam não: uma fstring depende de ser executada, ou seja - só tem seu valor renderizado quando a função é chamada. Uma docstring se torna um atributo do objeto função - independete da função jamais ser chamada ou não - ou seja, tem que ser conhecida "de fora". F-strings como docstrings não são uma opção, na verdade, sequer fazem sentido.

Comment: Poderiam, mas está fora do escopo explicar como fazer, eu sei como solucionar isso, pode até não ser do jeito que se espera, e claro, como eu disse não compensa o esforço porque não haverá um ganho real, não é algo que seja necessário, e não sei se está dentro que que propuseram fazer, mas o importante é que poderiam sim.

Comment: não poderiam não. :-) não sem destruir a linguagem. é Python, não uma linguagem hobbista que não se importaria em destruir a consistência em troca de uma feature que nem seria tão grande coisa. Em particular, não existe um frame da função com suas variáveis locais quando o objeto função é montado. Outro, que o código dentro de fstrings pode desencdear efeitos colaterais, já que pode chamar funções  - você teria algo dentro do corpo de uma função sendo desencadeado quando um módulo é simplesmente importado: isso não seria mais Python.