# Qual o nome desta estrutura em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

No seguinte código:

```
first_part = 46
last_part = 57
guess = f'{first_part}{last_part}'.encode()

print(guess)
print(type(guess))
```

Porém não entendi o trecho de código:

```
guess = f'{first_part}{last_part}'.encode()
```

Preciso de explicação ou o nome desta estrutura para que assim eu possa estudar.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 12):

Isso chama-se informalmente *f-strings*, mas o termo mais formal é [literal de interpolação de *strings*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). O `f` ali indica que o texto a seguir é um gabarito do que será usado, então dentro dele haverá texto normal e código que gerará uma parte do texto final, ou seja haverá execução do que está ali dentro. As partes que executarão estão entre chaves. Então neste caso imprimirá `4657` porque a indicação é que quer estes valores impressos um em seguida do outro. A parte do código é o que está entre chaves.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 9):

É conhecida por *f-string*, uma sintaxe nova adicionada ao Python na versão 3.6 para realizar interpolação de *strings*. Ela, necessariamente, deve possuir o prefixo `f` e todos os grupos entre chaves, `{var}`, serão analisados e substituídos pelos valores das respectivas variáveis, `var`.

No seu caso, o valor de `guess` será a *string* `'4657'`, pois `{first_part}` será avaliado como 46 e `{last_part}` como 57, fazendo a interpolação.

- [O que utilizar para formatar uma string, % ou format?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878)
- [Por que as f-strings não podem ser utilizadas como docstring?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/323171/5878)
- [Como fazer interpolação de string em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264702/5878)

Comment: Muito obrigado!