# Erro em média de alunos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Desenvolvi o seguinte algoritmo para calcular média de alunos:

```
matricula = int (input("Digite a matrícula do Aluno: "))

nota1  = float (input("Digite a primeira nota do aluno: "))
nota2  = float (input("Digite a primeira nota do aluno: "))
nota3  = float (input("Digite a primeira nota do aluno: "))


media = ( nota1 +  (nota2 * 2) + (nota3 * 3)) / 6

if media > 6 :
    print(" O Aluno  de matricula "+matricula, " Foi APROVADO com a média: "+media)

else:
    print(" O Aluno  de matricula "+matricula, " Foi REPROVADO com a média: "+media)
```

Aparece o seguinte erro:

> ```
> line 17, in <module>
>     print(" O Aluno  de matricula "+matricula, " Foi APROVADO com a média: "+media)
> TypeError: must be str, not int
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não precisa e não pode concatenar o texto com o número. Poderia converter o número para texto para poder concatenar, mas desnecessário fazer isto. Melhor só colocar cada argumento separado, usando vírgulas como chegou usar em parte.

```
matricula = int(input("Digite a matrícula do Aluno: "))
nota1  = float(input("Digite a primeira nota do aluno: "))
nota2  = float(input("Digite a primeira nota do aluno: "))
nota3  = float(input("Digite a primeira nota do aluno: "))
media = (nota1 +  (nota2 * 2) + (nota3 * 3)) / 6
if media > 6:
    print(" O Aluno  de matricula ", matricula, " Foi APROVADO com a média: ", media)
else:
    print(" O Aluno  de matricula ", matricula, " Foi REPROVADO com a média: ", media)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gpi10e). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/evnzwxti-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Print.py).

Comment: Perfeito, tinha me esquecido disso. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução é converter os dados de tipo numéricos em string, desta forma você consegue concatenar.

```
 print(" O Aluno  de matricula "+str(matricula), " Foi APROVADO com a média: "+str(media))
```

Answer (score 1):

Se está utilizando Python 3.6 ou superior, pode utilizar as *f-string*:

```
resultado = 'APROVADO' if media > 6 else 'REPROVADO'
print(f'O aluno de matricula {matricula} foi {resultado} com a média {media}')
```

- [Qual o nome desta estrutura em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/332601/5878)
- [O que utilizar para formatar uma string, % ou format?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878)
- [Como fazer interpolação de string em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264702/5878)